# matplotlib and geopandas cannot plot world maps with center at China

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I would like to have map vizualized in matplotlib with its center to China (or 180 longitude), but I don't know why my script crushes.

I wrote code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import geopandas

path = geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres') # get layer of world from geopandas library
df = geopandas.read_file(path)

df_epsg= pyproj.Proj(proj='eqc', ellps='WGS84', datum='WGS84', lat_0=0, lon_0=180).srs  #reproject it to my projection with central longitude set to 180
df = df.to_crs(crs=df_epsg)
df.plot()
```

Comment: What happens? And what should happen?
I see the map centered as expected. The issue is that some polygons are on the edge now and those need to be taken care of.